# Plotting cylinder with revolution plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm trying to come up with a way to plot 3d hollow cylinder with major axis aligned with z-axis, given following constants:

- inner radius `r`
- outer radius `R`
- bottom base height `h`
- top base height `H`
- starting angle `alpha`
- ending angle `beta`

In theory, revolving a square around z-axis from `alpha` to `beta` seems to be able to accomplish the given task, however, I cannot come up with its implementation in Mathematica. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The routines in the linked thread could be modified to account for start and end angles in your case.

Comment: @J.M., Thanks a lot. Turns out that the shape I was interested in is called annulus. My bad. Nevertheless, I'm still curious how it could be implemented with RevolutionPlot :)